# FindViewById and multiple layouts for different screen densities (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

my question has to do with using different layouts for different screen densities on the Android platform.

Let's say that I have four main.xml files (each in their respective folders for their corresponding screen densities:  ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi) and let's say that they're all identical to start with.  But let's say I want to get rid of some of the UI elements for the ldpi layout.  How do I handle things on the Java side to avoid a null pointer exception when it tries to find that view in the ldpi layout on a ldpi phone?  Should I just check and see if findviewbyid returns null and move on from there?

I realize that you're supposed to keep things uniform in your apps, but on occasion it just seems like it'd make more sense to just get rid of a convenient but otherwise unnecessary UI element.  I love having the extra real-estate on these new phones, but if/when it comes time to make a ldpi layout, I'd rather not just cram everything in there when it'd look better just to get rid of some stuff, if that makes any sense!

Comment: There's another question one might ask himself. How many ldpi devices are still there? E.g. when I downloaded official ICS icon pack, there were no ldpi versions. To be honest I try to make my app work on ldpi devices, but don't optimize the layouts to fit them. In my case it's not worth the time

Comment: That's true-- I'm not really sweating ldpi support too much.  Heck, even this junky Droid Eris test phone I bought uses mdpi!  That said, I'm still interested in all of the different ways to go about handling this problem.

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for and you probably know it, but someone seeing this thread might be interested. You can always make a `layout-nodpi` folder with fallback layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Good question. Null checking can be one of the solutions.
another solution is checking screen properties. look at this example:

```
public static boolean isTabletPC(Context context) {
        boolean isHoneycomb = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
        boolean hasLargeScreen = (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
        return isHoneycomb & hasLargeScreen;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is handled the same way as handling any optional element. Check if it exists (not null) and handle accordingly. In case of a non-existent `View`,  `findViewById` will return null and you can operate further on the `View` inside a `if(null != view){}` block or if there are multiple optional elements that can be grouped, you can use an instance variable.

[HoneycombGallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html) demo gives an idea of how you can detect device properties using layouts (although in the demo, it is done for fragments, it can be applied for any View)

Answer (score 0):

From api lvl 11 you would probably want to use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) for that. This way your java code always deals with views that are definately there, and your layout can show (or not) certain fragments that take care of their own business.

I would advice against littering your code with checks for what kind of screen you have, and checking if a certain view might be in the screen.

If you look at figure one on the linked page, you see a clear example of what i mean:

[image: fragments on different devices]

Comment: what you do with different resolutions on multiple devices?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You can make layouts for different devices so you can scale and fit etc, and as soon as you are going to have some part of the interface _not there_ (like above example), you split it. So all devices that get fragment A see the same contents (but maybe based on different pictures (resolution) etc), and screens that don't get the parts of the UI that don't fit well.. they don't get it (again, in above example. the tablet got fragment B, but the handset didn't // has to go to another activity)

Comment: I mean maybe sometimes programmer needs to specify some features to its UI according to device resolution. for example creating a custom keyboard needs different features for different resolutions. How can he determine device resolution in his code in your solution?

Comment: Most situations where you think you need the resolution, you don't. and were getting a bit away from the origional question (or how I read it), namely how to stop from having to check if a view is there all the time: the answer is as far as I'm concerned, that you don't: you make sure your code fits your layouts, and show correct code (fragment) for correct situations. Now if you think you need to know details, you can find that quite easily (use `DisplayMetrics`, loads of questions about that here), but I'd avoid that. Stick to the defined 'categories' as much as you can!

Comment: I'd checked into fragments before-- I love where Google is going with them, very useful.  Unfortunately, cutting off support at API 11 is not a viable option for me right now.